# Factors that determine the geology of a planet (what factors determine the elemental composition of the planet)

Tags: planets, physics, hard-science, geology, worldbuilding-resources

This is my first world and I want to build in a way that is physically possible (if this is possible, otherwise make the necessary changes) for my civilization (which is mostly fleshed out) but I don't know where to start.

I am looking for an introduction to the exact science, in the same way, that python serves as an introduction to programming (for some).

{Books, textbooks, youtube channels, websites etc}

*on the civilization for whoever is interested*

my civilization is made of human-sized arthropods (with approx 1830 tech) that live in flying cities that are connected to the canopies of huge trees (for which the bugs build systems in order to help the trees grow taller) by cables. on the ground live massive mammals that slowly tread between the trees and in the air massive flying creatures ascend from the canopies to snatch a few bugs from a city (they can only fly for a short time based on their size). They get their minerals (and other resources which they lack) through mineral fruits made by the trees because of a very long symbiosis between them that caused them to evolve to suit the bugs' needs. because of the high atmospheric pressure and low gravity of the planet (which I know require a high temperature), the bugs also build flying contraptions easily.

Addendum:
I know that there is a list with a lot of info on worldb building (climate, mining, economy, etc. [A list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources)) But I couldn't find anything in it about what affects the elements inside the planet (Iron, Carbon, copper etc.) And on the composition of the core and the mantle. But If I would love to know if I missed something.

Addendum 2:
There is a similar question [Creating a realistic world map - Mineralogy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25084/creating-a-realistic-world-map-mineralogy) that covers the location of minerals on the surface of a planet, this question is focused on the elements themselves and not the materials that are composed from them, for an answer on what minerals will be present and where they will be distributed go to the link above.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are some books, textbooks, youtube channels and other sources that are informative.

Comment: especially on the physical and chemical composition of worlds

Comment: Make that clear in the question, not in the comments, please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources)

Comment: As to your addendum: [this qustion about mineralogy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/25084/6986) is included in the suggested duplicate. If your concern is rather what the planet is made of when it forms, then I have to ask why it matters. Barring clarification, I'm agreeing with the duplicate vote.

Comment: The answer to the question explains where minerals would be found once you know what resources you want. I'm asking what factors determine what these resources are (such as m/r^2 for the type of core). Ill try to edit the description to make that clear.I'm asking this question because of two reasons

Comment: One) because the science behind it is fascinating for me and (before this question) I haven't found any sources that explained it in a way that I understood and everything that I found was very specific (I want to know not only the equations behind this process but also how they work)

Comment: Two) because I want to create not only a story but also a full world in which it is set because I love speculative evolution planets and want to create one on my own (and it's awesome how one variable leads to another (which I wouldn't think up on my own) with the right equations) with as many facts as possible (I'm a sucker for small details) and which can physically exist because it's awesome to Imagine that such a world may exist in real life.

Comment: My civilization is also be pretty advanced so I want to know what elements will be available to them (because (with their level of texhnology) they'll be able to extract a few).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than copying the list of resources to here, I suggest that interested parties browse the answer to this previous question ([A list of worldbuilding-resources?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources)) where an *humongous long list* of resources is to be found.

You could do worse than start with this intro youtube vid to the [solar system's geology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKkK_ci9ZsQ).

Here's another touching on [some big moons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKJCOpLe9m4) of the solar system.

I'm pleased to say that there are related and potentially [useful Q&As](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=exoplanet) on Earthsciences.se, as some exoplanet and speculative issues are dealt with there from time to time.

Comment: Thank you, I checked most of the resources on the list and I may have missed something but I couldn't find any on what determines which materials make up the planet is made and how its internal composition is determined (core, mantel, etc).

Comment: Frustrating isn't it, there's odd tidbits of info turns up in various places, but as far as I can see not a single go-to resource. This is partly why I added the you-tube vids, they're more specifically on-topic. If I find anything else I'll add it to my answer and ping you.