# Tips and principles for creating an accurate elevation map?

Tags: earth, geology, worldbuilding-process

I'm continuing to hash out the map of my world, using tutorials found on this site and elsewhere.

In [some tutorials](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/989/37212) the starting elevation levels of a planet are treated pretty randomly, implying that while tectonic, volcanic, or eroding activity may be required for distinct features like mountains or gorges, larger scale elevation features (highlands, valleys, large plateaus) may be more up to the whim of the author, if rooted and justified by in the earliest shape of the planet.

Is this correct, or are there other constraining factors that I'm not aware of. As example, does this elevation map (with tectonic plates below it) included currently look realistic?

[image: Elevation Map]

[image: Tectonic Plates]

Finally, and in general, is there anything else I should consider when making an elevation map?

Comment: You seem to have some drops of 4km where the land hits the sea.....

Comment: @sdfgeoff fair, I’ll nudge the mountains in a little

Comment: Since you are using the Mercator projection the south continent needs to bulge and reach end to end at the very bottom.

Comment: @skout it's an eqirectangular grid, it's not based on mercator. as it stands, the map would only cover half of the world based on that grid. but you're right, if it would be the pole covered with land, the southern continent needs to be (visually) streched.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an ocean? sea level as a starting point for elevation?  If it seems pretty random, who would be checking to see whether your map is accurate or not? It's your world, afterall.

Try referring to contour/topographical maps.  They do show elevation, but more detail than the 1st map you provided (which seems fine for a generalized/simplified world view.  But assuming you will have more detailed maps of certain key locations, I would suggest using topographical maps showing contour lines (not necessarily only a contour map).

Examples (with links to images provided, also helpful information pertaining to reading maps, in any interest):

[image]

*Shown to illustrate elevation with contour lines.*
[image source](https://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/topo-maps-how-to-use.html)

[image]

*Another example.*
[image source](https://archive.cnx.org/contents/7b8a84e5-0b3c-4e52-ab90-004506ecfec0@1/reading-contour-patterns-on-a-topographic-map)

[image]

*More detail is provided. Note that elevation is marked along some lines.*
[image source](http://earthscience4reveryone.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-read-contour-map.html)
[image]

*Even more detail and information is provided, but still simplified*
[image source](http://www.wanderingvirginia.com/2012/05/virginia-topographic-maps.html)

[image]

*A more aesthetically pleasing map, still provided with elevation markings, and much easier to read*
[image source](http://www.lib.berkeley.edu/EART/tour/topo.html)

Comment: Bumpy I think you missed the main question about starting elevation in your answer.  I'd suggest you edit to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Note that the OP had incorrectly linked images in the question. These have been corrected. You may want to review your answer with respect to the changes.

Comment: @Frostfyre I'm not sure I understand how that pertains to this answer. I clicked on the images, and it just shows a larger image.

Comment: The OP was interested if the supplied depictions were reasonable. This analysis should have been part of any answer to the question. I didn't read your answer; I was only letting you know that the question had changed.

Comment: @Frostfyre This is why I said "Try referring to contour/topographical maps."  The OP only mentioned elevation.